# xcode 7 Timer with Limit

Tags: ios, swift2, nstimer

I´ve already made an app with a timer, but now I want that the timer stops after a period of time, for example after 10 seconds. When the timer is over, it goes to the next view controller. I would be happy if anyone can help me. Thank you in advance. This is the code I already have:

import UIKit

class Level1: UIViewController {

```
var timerCount = 0
var timmerRunning = false
var timer = NSTimer()



@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!

func Counting() {
  timerCount += 1
    timerLabel.text = "\(timerCount)"

}


@IBAction func startButton(sender: UIButton) {

    if timmerRunning == false{
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Counting"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                 self.timmerRunning = true
    }

}



@IBAction func stopButton(sender: UIButton) {


    if timmerRunning == true{

        self.timer.invalidate()
           self.timmerRunning = false
    }

}

@IBAction func restartButton(sender: UIButton) {

    timerCount = 0
    timerLabel.text = "0"

}





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
func Counting() {
      timerCount += 1
        timerLabel.text = "\(timerCount)"

    if timerCount == 10 {
        self.timer.invalidate()
        //go to the next view controller, you'll need to create a navigation controller if you don't have one
        navigaionController.pushViewController(someViewController, animated:false)
        }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot but when I want to run it, it shows me the error: Cannot convert value of type ´String´ to expected arguments type ÚIViewController´  I would be happy if you can help me (#I´m dumb). Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to create a view controller before the line pushViewController.
It will be something like: let myViewController = UIViewController(name and some params I dont remember) , and only then do the pushViewController